# .net MemoryCache - notify on item removed

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

I'm using a .net Memory Cache with .NET 4.0 and c#, I want my application to be notified when an item is removed (so I can write that it has been removed to a log file or notify the UI, that the item is removed).

Is there anyway to do this.

I'm using  System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache not System.Web.Caching

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**EDIT**: If you're using the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` there is a [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.removedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `CacheItemPolicy` object for deletion, as well as one for update.

```
myMemoryCache.Set("key", null, new CacheItemPolicy() {RemovedCallback = new CacheEntryRemovedCallback(CacheRemovedCallback) /* your other parameters here */});

public void CacheRemovedCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
{
    // do what's needed
}
```

**Initial answer**

When [inserting data in the .net cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `System.Web.Caching` namespace you have the option to set a callback to be notified of removal

```
Cache.Insert("data", "", null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheRemovedCallback));

public string CacheRemovedCallback(String key, object value, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason removedReason)
{
    // here you can log, renew the value, etc...
}
```

There is also a signature for the `Insert` method that lets you specify a callback to be [notified before the item is removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm not using System.Web.Caching.Cache, I'm using System.Runtime.Caching MemoryCache, I've updated the question to say this.

Comment: @DermFrench: Edited to point out the callback on `CacheItemPolicy`

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out and see if it works can you edit your actual code above, still says System.Web.Caching in it, so I can accept as answer, maybe put in a) this is how you do it if using web.caching, b) this is how you do it if using System.Runtime.Caching.