# Caching and multi-thread synchronization with ReaderWriterLockSlim

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching

I have a web-service which is called by some web-service clients. This web-service returns the current inventory list of an inventory. This list can be big, 10K+ of product IDs, and it takes quite some time (~4 minutes) to refresh the list by reading data in the database. I don't want to refresh the list every time this web-service is called, as it may consume too much resource on my database server, and the performance is always not very good.

What I intend to do is giving the inventory list some time-to-live value, which means when a client asks for the inventory list, if the data is not out-of-date I just return the data right away; if the data is obsolete I will read it from the database, update this list data and its time-to-live value, and then return the refreshed data back to the web-service client. As there may be several clients call this web-service, It looks like I need a multi-thread synchronization(multiple-read single-write, **ReaderWriterLockSlim** class?) to protect this inventory list, but I haven't found a good design to make this web-service have good performance: ***only one client refreshes the data, the other clients don't have to redo the work if the data is still within the time-to-live frame and the web-service should return the result as soon as possible after the write thread completes the update***.

I also think about another solution (also use **ReaderWriterLockSlim** class): creating a separate thread to refresh the inventory list periodically (write-thread refreshes the data every 15 minutes), and let all the web-service clients use read-thread to read the data. This may work, but I don't really like it as this solution still waste resource of the web-server. For example, if there is no client's request, the system still has to refresh the inventory list data every 15 minutes.

Please suggest some solution. Thanks.

Comment: `For example, if there is no client's request, the system still has to refresh the inventory list data every 15 minutes.` You could keep track of the last UTC datetime that a request occurred, and only do a refresh if that date was in the last 15 minutes. _That does mean the data can get quite stale if load is low over a sustained period of time though._

Comment: If there is no client's request, I don't have to update the inventory list as no one cares about it. Only when there is a client's request, if the current list is out-of-date, the system has to refresh the data and then return the update result to the client. If there are two requests check the list at the same time, and we may end up updating the out-of-date list twice, which is not I want.
I would like to have the 2nd thread waiting the the 1st thread to finish the update to read the result. So I may have to use some double multi-thread locking.

Comment: That would work - the only downside that the 2nd thread blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `MemoryCache`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22935978/34092 can be used to detect when the item expires. *https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kxdx246.aspx is also worth a read.*

At this point, the first line of the code you write (in `CacheRemovedCallback`) should write the value back to the `MemoryCache` - this will allow readers to keep reading it.

Then it should get the latest data, and then write that new data to the MemoryCache (again passing in a `CacheItemPolicy` to allow the callback to be called when the latest version is removed). And so on and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever run only one instance of your service? Then in-memory caching is enough for you. Or use a ConcurrentDictionary if you don't want to implement the lock yourself.

If you run multiple instances of that services, it might be advisable to use a out of process cache like Redis.

Also, you could eventually maintain the cached list so that it is always in sync with what you have in the database!?

There are many different cache vendors dotnet and asp.net and asp.net core have different solutions. For distributed caching there are also many different options. Just pick whatever fits best for the framework you use.

You can also use libraries like [CacheManager](http://cachemanager.michaco.net) to help you implement what you need more easily.